# Как вызвать функцию, если её имя является свойством объекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как я понял, если бы имя функции было бы значением объекта, проблем бы не было.
Но как перебрав объект oError можно вызвать функции required и minlength ?
Спасибо =)

UPD:
Вот сейчас подумал добавить все нужны функции в ещё один объект. И от туда их вызывать. Поправьте если это не правильно и нужно как то по другому делать или просто есть какие то другие способы.

```js
var oError = {
  username: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
  } 
};
var oFunc = { 
    required: function() { alert('Функция required сработала.'); }, 
    minlength: function() { alert('Функция minlength сработала.'); } 
} 
for ( var index in oError['username'] ) {
  oFunc[index]();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно тебя понял. Все глобальные функции доступны в объекте `window`. В твоем случае мы можем к ним обратиться вызывая `window["имя функции"]` и вызвать, добавив скобки.

```js
var oError = {
  username: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
  } 
};

function required () {
  alert('Функция required сработала.');
}
function minlength () {
  alert('Функция minlength сработала.');
}

for (let key in oError) {
    for (let functionName in oError[key]) {
        window[functionName]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, рассматривал такое решение. на форуме видел обсуждения использования window и eval. Но там развели срач и писали, что и то и то "Дурной тон") В окончании так и не понял дурной или нет и что дурнее))

Comment: `eval` - дурной. Желательно избегать его использование. Через `window` скорее костыль. У вас изначально что-то не так с архитектурой - получается спагетти код. Такие проблемы обычно просто не возникают.

Comment: ага, наверное с архитектурой. Так как только изучаю и ещё много не знаю как делать правильно, поэтому часто делаю как делается)

Comment: @Misha Saidov Михаил, поздравляю с первой круглой репой :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT это же все Дед Мороз?)

Comment: @MishaSaidov C Наступающим Новым годом! Желаю новых творческих успехов, ярких работ и признания.